# Lombok PropertyNotWritableException jsf

Tags: java, jsf, lombok

I'm developing one project using jsf and primefaces I was tired of getters and setters and decided to use lombok project to get rid of it.
So I've created simple page. there I have:

```
<p:inputText value ="#{advert.advertId}"/>
<p:commandLink style="color:white" value ="change" update="form"/>
```

My bean:

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "advert")
public class AdvertController
        extends AbstractManagedBean<SessionInfo> implements Serializable {

    @EJB
    private DatabaseManager dbManager;

    @Getter
    private Advert ad;
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private Integer advertId;

}
```

But when I press my button I get this exeption.

> Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /advert.xhtml @17,60 value=" #{advert.advertId}": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
>       at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:136)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIInput.updateModel(UIInput.java:832)
>       ... 41 more
>
> Caused by: javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Illegal Syntax for
>   Set Operation     at
>   com.sun.el.parser.SimpleNode.setValue(SimpleNode.java:168)    at
>   com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.setValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:294)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.setValue(WeldValueExpression.java:64)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.setValue(TagValueExpression.java:131)
>     ... 42 more

Any ideas?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the Lombok annotations and use "real" getters and setters instead? Othwerwise, could it have to do with `advertId` being an integer?